# Given a date/time string, w javascript/jquery, how can you determine if it is today or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a date/time string, example:

```
2010-12-12 19:27:00Z
```

Using JS/jQuery how can you easily determine if that is today or not?

Thanks

Comment: How could you possibly do that with *any* language?

Comment: Any ISO 8601 date/time string from the database...

Comment: Well in this case we have the ISO 8601 date/time string and the client's browser which has Date.today to compare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use <strike>`Date.parse` to convert the string to a timestamp</strike> `new Date` to parse the string into a `Date` object.

```
var date = '2010-12-12 19:27:00Z',
    // then = new Date(Date.parse(date)),
    then = new Date(date),
    // Firefox doesn't support dates in this format
    // you can covert it to an accepted format like this:
    // then = new Date(date.replace(/(.*) (.*)Z/,'$1T$2'))
    now = new Date;
```

Then you can compare the dates.

```
if(then.toDateString() === now.toDateString())
```

Comment: `2010-12-12 19:27:00Z` is invalid date to firefox 12.0

Comment: `var date = new Date('2012-06-07 19:27:00Z'.replace(/-/g,'/').replace('Z','0'))` works in firefox 12.0

Comment: @Jashwant: I would suggest `new Date('2012-06-07 19:27:00Z'.replace(/(.*) (.*)Z/,'$1T$2'))` instead.

Comment: That goes above my head. I do not know regex. Just pointing out the problem with firefox.

Comment: @Jashwant: Oh, ok. Thanks though, that is an issue. :-P

Comment: Btw, +1 for great solution :)

Answer (score 5):

If your dates will always be in exactly this format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SSZ
```

Then this should do it:

```
var input = '2010-12-12 19:27:00Z';
var year  = parseInt(input.substring(0, 4),  10);
var month = parseInt(input.substring(5, 7),  10);
var day   = parseInt(input.substring(8, 10), 10);
var d     = new Date();

if(d.getUTCFullYear() === year && d.getUTCMonth() + 1 === month && d.getUTCDate() === day) {
    // It's today
} else {
    // It's not
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work, though this makes the assumption that the month and day fields will always be 2 digits.

```
    var dateInput = "2010-12-12 19:27:00Z"
    var date = dateInput.substring(0, 10); //"2010-12-12"
    var d = new Date();
    var today = d.getFullYear() + "-" + ( d.getMonth() + 1 ) + "-" + d.getDate();

    if( date == today )
        match = true;
    else
        match = false;
```

Comment: How about `match = date === today`?

Comment: I'm just keeping it simple for readability and ease of understanding.

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = new Date('2012-06-07 19:27:00Z');
var curr = new Date();
var iDate = input.getDate+'-'+input.getMonth()+'-'+input.getFullYear();
var currDate = curr.getDate+'-'+curr.getMonth()+'-'+curr.getFullYear();
if(iDate== currDate){
    console.log("today");
}else{
    console.log("not");
}
```

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XJ4kn/)